# How to optimize site like Digg (Less Content but High Qulaity Links)

Tags: seo, google

I already read [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

But what is going to build isn't a normal blog or a normal website.

I want to build a site like Digg for a **specific niche**.

For example, get "WordPress" as a niche. So categories will be like WordPress Tips, WordPress Themes, WordPress Plugins, WordPress Hosting, etc.

I have found 50+ Categories for my niche. So there will be 50 pages. category count will be increased slowly.

What can I do to increase rank on those specific pages? I asked this question all those pages have around 30,40 links with images.

But those links will be added by manually and users can rank them. So, those link will be high quality.

I can add a short description to the category also.

Still, I have doubt that this project will fail because I have doubt Google won't give good ranking for these category pages.

Any special tip to increase the ranking of these type of site?

Comment: Questions seeking "tips" are unfortunately too broad for this site's format. They really need to be asking [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which is why the community wiki was created to address broadly-scoped ones seeking tips. You could possibly edit this to ask something more specific, such as if adding `a short description to the category` might help.

Comment: Backlinks are the key! If you can generate good linking to your site, then all is fine